# oracle regular expression issue

Tags: sql, regex, oracle11g

I have been trying to find the records which are non printable (i.e between ASCII 32 to 127), below i have mentioned the as per the query it should print all records with chr either less than 32 or more then 127  but it does not show the records with chr(160), while it do show the records with chr(10)

```
select regexp_instr(a.COL, '[^[:print:]]$') as STRING_POSITION,
       a.COL, dump(col)
from tq84_compare a
where regexp_instr(a.COL, '[^[:print:]]') > 0;

insert into tq84_compare
    values (11, chr(10));

insert into tq84_compare
    values (11, chr(160));
```

insert into tq84_compare
values
(101,'On-line'||chr(160)||chr(160)||chr(160));

Comment: 160 code is a hard space, right? It is expected behavior since `[:print:]` matches `[\x20-\x7E]`, space and all other printable ASCII chars.

Comment: how can we remove it as because trim does not work on chr(160)

Comment: Do you mean you need to remove any whitespace from the start/end of the entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match Unicode hard space with `[:space:]`, nor `[^[:print:]]`, nor `\s` patterns.

You may trim the strings with [the following solution](http://rextester.com/OIDJ85579):

```
select regexp_replace(' some stuff  ', '^[[:space:] ]+|[[:space:] ]+$', '') as result from dual
```

where the space inside is a hard space. The `^[[:space:] ]+` will match all ASCII whitespace and/or hard spaces at the start of the string and `[[:space:] ]+$` will match all ASCII whitespace chars and a hard space at the end of the string.

If you want to add a hard space to your `[^[:print:]]`, you need to use an alternation:

```
select regexp_replace(' some stuff  ', '^([^[:print:]]| )+|([^[:print:]]| )+$', '') as result from dual
```

See [this online demo](http://rextester.com/EPAE99100).